# Titanium Alloy: Can a xml view have nested views with the same id?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm studing [Codestrong 2012 app](https://github.com/appcelerator/Codestrong) and trying to make it work on SDK 3.1.3.

I thought xml views should have unique id's, but I've found this:

```
//main.xml
<Alloy>
    <View id="container">
        <View id="content">  </View>
        <!-- ... -->
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

and

```
//drawer.xml
<Alloy>
    <View id="container">
        <!-- ... -->
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

then, mains.js controller have a piece of code that does:

```
var d = Alloy.createController('drawer');
    // ...
    $.container.add(d.getView());
```

***How come drawer.xml have a view with id=container added within main.xml which also have a view with a id=container ?***

**Is this ok ?**

**how could you access second #container form main controller?**

Answer (score 0):

In case which you are describing two different views are dynamically combined together but ids are accessible through different objects: `$` for main.xml and `d` for drawer.xml.

So for example you can access:

- `<View id="container">` from drawer.xml by:
  `d.container`
- `<View id="content">` from main.xml by:
  `$.content`
- `<View id="container">` from main.xml by:
  `$.container`

Comment: So dynamically combining views doesn't viollates any id's rules within Titanium views? I mean, it's not like HTML?

Comment: Would it be possible to do something like $.container.container ? Ok. I guess I'll try it on debugger.